# Abstract class pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-class

The abstract C++ class is a class for which at least one pure virtual method exits.(i.e one can`t instantiate it)
Why and when the pointer to the abstract class should be used?
The only situation I can think about - is classical polymorphic base class pointer which behaves differently based on dispatch table.
Are there any additional reasons?

**Upd.**
Is class  abstract if its constructor is private?

Comment: Polymorphism is a sufficient reason IMHO.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: noooooo.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth I guess you meant the private constructor question?

Comment: @g-makulik no, I commented before the edit - "are there any additional reasons - no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only situation I can think about - is classical polymorphic base class pointer

Yes, that's exactly what abstract classes are used for, and the only non-bizarre use for them.

> Is class abstract if its constructor is private?

No. That class can still be instantiated, but only by its members or friends. An abstract class can't be instantiated at all.

Comment: '... only by its members or friends.' There are other doggy possibilities using `new`. For instance, one can dynamically allocate an instace of a class with a `private` destructor and never `delete` the pointer (producing a memory leak). I'm not saying that this is good (**it's not**). I'm just saying it's possible.

Comment: @CassioNeri: Indeed, you can instantiate a class with a private destructor. But not one with only private constructors, which is what we're considering here.

Answer (score 0):

You would use base class pointers to store a collection of disparate objects.  Then you could do operations on the items as a group.